# How to produce a relatively uniform magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism

How to do this using equipments common to a high school lab besides a solenoid?

Answer (score 3):

It depends a lot on what exactly you have available, and how large a volume you want.  Consider [Helmholtz Coils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_coil).  Most distributors of high school lab equipment have them for sale, or you can make them yourself if you have time and resources.  And don't forget that Earth's magnetic field will be rather constant in your lab.